# New Angular app in Visual Studio, lots of JavaScript errors in polyfill.js

Tags: angular

I have a new Angular app. If I run it using 'ng serve' then I don't appear to have any errors, if I run it within Visual Studio 2017 then I get lots of errors in the debug output window, e.g

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 137.0021ms 404 text/html; charset=utf-8
Exception was thrown at line 2584, column 55 in http://localhost:50055/polyfills.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object.getPrototypeOf: 'this' is not an Object
Exception was thrown at line 2584, column 55 in http://localhost:50055/polyfills.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object.keys: argument is not an Object
Exception was thrown at line 2584, column 55 in http://localhost:50055/polyfills.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only happens when running in IE (yes, I have to support it), and only when Script debugging is enabled (Under the menu in the 'IIS Express' dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the following lines in your polyfill.ts file   (found in src/app)

> /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
>
> import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/object';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/function';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/number';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/math';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/string';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/date';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/array';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/map';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
>
> import 'core-js/es6/set';

Comment: They were already uncommented, I think you have to just to get the basics working